# sql Max() on Varchar

Tags: sql-server

in sql server, I have a employment table

```
name, pay_grade
 A      MA
 A      DV
 A      BB
 A      GC
```

a guy might have multiple employment, but I am only interested in the one with the highest pay_grade, in order to get a single row

problem is the pay_grade is ordered desc as (MA, BB, GC, DV) I can't do a MAX() on them

in Java I could define a Map, then put a order line (1, MM)
(2, BB)

but In sql how do I do it?

Comment: what is the parameter to check maximum `pay_grade`

Comment: What the order from max to min in pay_grade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using at least sql server 2008 and your list ist static and you use the values only once you could create a table value:

```
select e.name, substring(max(pg),3,99)
from employment e 
join ( values ('1-MA'), ('2-BB'), ('3-GC')) v(pg) on e.pay_grade=substring(pg,3,99)
group by e.name
```

the construct `values ('1-MA'), ('2-BB'), ('3-GC')) v(pg)` creates a virtual table with the name `v` and a single column `pg`

another way to write it ( should work in many db):

```
select e.name
     , substring(
         max(
           case e.pay_grade 
             when 'MA' then '1-MA'
             when 'BB' then '2-BB'
             when 'GC' then '3-GC'
           end
         )
       ,3,99)             
from employment e 
group by e.name
```

and just for fun an oracle version ( haven't used oracle for a while, maybe there is some fancy solution around) :

```
select e.name
     , substr(  
         max(
           DECODE (e.pay_grade, 'MA', '1-MA', 
                                'BB', '2-BB', 
                                'GC', '3-GC',
                                'z-00') 
         )
       ,3,99)             
from employment e 
group by e.name
```

Comment: 2 questions what is v(pg) ? and is your solution the only solution out there? many thanks

Comment: @A ツ no sure better, just any alternatives out of interests

Comment: @A ツ also what would you do the same in Oracle?

Comment: better as in better answer not better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using grade in Ascending order. if so then you can use limit and order by  as following

```
select TOP(1) * from employmenttable where name = 'name' order by pay_grade ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a table where you define the single values for each pay_grade. Then you could get the highest rate from that new table and join over with the name to your data.

```
select * from YourTable 
 where pay_grade = (
        select pay_grade 
          from NEWTABLE 
         where pay_grade_rate = (select max(pay_grade_rate) from NEWTABLE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a lookup table for the pay ranks like below and then use this to `JOIN` to:

```
CREATE TABLE #pay_ranks
    (
      pay_grade VARCHAR(2) ,
      pay_rank INT
    )

INSERT  INTO #pay_ranks
        ( pay_grade, pay_rank )
VALUES  ( 'MA', 1 ),
        ( 'BB', 2 ),
        ( 'GC', 3 )
```

Then returning data can be done in multiple ways, here's one:

```
CREATE TABLE #employee
    (
      name VARCHAR(5) ,
      pay_grade VARCHAR(2)
    )

INSERT  INTO #employee
        ( name, pay_grade )
VALUES  ( 'A', 'MA' ),
        ( 'A', 'BB' ),
        ( 'A', 'GC' )

SELECT  e.name ,
        pr.pay_grade ,
        pr.pay_rank
FROM    #employee e
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT TOP 1
                            pay_grade ,
                            pay_rank
                     FROM   #pay_ranks
                     ORDER BY pay_rank
                   ) pr ON pr.pay_grade = e.pay_grade


DROP TABLE #employee
DROP TABLE #pay_ranks
```

**Output**

```
name    pay_grade   pay_rank
A       MA          1
```